# using cairo with gtk3

Tags: c, gtk, cairo, gtk3

I am trying to draw a scatterplot with cairo in gtk3. To start, I am using the examples here: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/cairographicstutorial/

They compile with gtk2 successfully but display no image. They do not compile with gtk3 but give the following error:

```
example.c: In function ‘on_expose_event’:
example.c:17:31: error: ‘GtkWidget’ has no member named ‘window’
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

btw I am using writing using ArchLinux for this if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There have been quite a few changes in Gtk3. There is no member `window` exposed as part of `GtkWidget` anymore, the members have been moved to `GtkWidgetPrivate` which is an opaque structure so you cannot access the members directly from `GtkWidget`. You will have to use accessor function, in this case where you need `window` member of `GtkWidget` you can use [`gtk_widget_get_window`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-window), but that may not fix the code sample with which you are working. Please note that the `expose_event` signal has been replaced with `draw` signal so you will need to update the function which is actually drawing appropriately (`on_expose_event` in your case I think). Please refer [this link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch26s02.html#id-1.6.3.4.4) to see the list of changes needed to switch to Gtk3. You can refer source provided by `gtk-demo` application or `demos/gtk-demo` from Gtk3 source code to get sample code.
Regarding image not being shown in case of Gtk2, if you are working with image sample, please make sure that the image file is available in the path mentioned in the source.
Hope this helps!