# ‘GtkWidget {aka struct _GtkWidget}’ has no member named ‘window’

Tags: gtk3

I have recently tried my hand at learning GTK using Andrew Krause's "Foundations of GTK+ Development" (this is the most recent - 2007 - book on GTK I could find).  Thus far, about half of the programs compile & run outright and the other half have deprecated functions which I can find replacements for with a little googling.  I do use some online tutorials but they don't have the detail of explanation that Mr. Krause's book has.

In a perfect world, I would like to have an up to date book to learn from but that is not available.  Thus I have to go back and forth between the book (GTK2) and online sources (GTK3).

My question, when I try to compile the source code from the book, I get several errors. I have been able to update all of the code except for the issue I name in the title that I cannot get past.

From the book, chapter 3 event boxes, this line is the one I am having trouble with:

```
gdk_window_set_cursor (eventbox->window, gdk_cursor_new (GDK_HAND1));
```

I have been able to modify it to work to this point but still get the error when I compile:

```
gdk_window_set_cursor (eventbox->window, gdk_cursor_new_for_display   (gdk_display_get_default(), GDK_HAND1));
```

When I compile I get:

```
eventboxes.c:37:33: error: ‘GtkWidget {aka struct _GtkWidget}’ has no member named ‘window’


gdk_window_set_cursor (eventbox->window, gdk_cursor_new_for_display (gdk_display_get_default(), GDK_HAND1));
```

Having read some other items online such as this one "[using cairo with gtk3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722084/using-cairo-with-gtk3)"

I have found that changes between GTK2 and GTK3 have made members, such as window, inaccessible.

Sorry for the longwinded post by my question is:
Is there a way in GTK3 to make the line of code work or I am just pursuing a fool's errand and should let this one die?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exact code can be fixed the following way:

```
GdkWindow * gdk_window = gtk_widget_get_window (eventbox);
gdk_window_set_cursor (gdk_window, gdk_cursor_new (GDK_HAND1));
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea to learn Gtk3 with Gtk2 books. You can read them to get overall view, but then switch to gtk documentation, `gtk3-demo` app for some recipes, `gtk3-widget-factory` source code and, of course, SO.

Comment: Awesome - thank you Alexander!  That worked well.   I concur completely on the problem of using GTK2 to learn GTK3 - my problem is that I am so green on this I don't even know where to start (if it was available, I would love to have a book on GTK4 in the future).  My plan is to try to finish the Krause book to get an overall feel of GTK in general then switch completely over to online documentation and help after that.

Comment: @Jman Accept the answer, if it's helpful. I took a look at that book. Chapter 2 gives shows you how to write and compile basic Gtk application, chapter 6 has also useful information. From my point of view, after that you can switch to Gtk3 and study everything you are interested in using resources mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, I did upvote but forgot to click accepted answer checkmark (which I just did).  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: In your first line `GdkWindow * gdk_window = gtk_widget_get_window (window);` what is `window`?  Shouldn't that be `eventbox`?